# Python 3.7 Openpyxl 2.5.11 wrong value of max rows and columns

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I can't understand why `openpyxl` shows right value of `ws.max_row` but when I iterate to print all cell values from a column, I see only last value with coordinates `(201, col_id)`

Excel spreadsheet size is `202 rows:67 columns`, here I count columns only with headers, as MS Excel does. 
`Openpyxl` counts  `max_rows, max_col: 202 rows:97 columns`
Nothing wrong here, other 30 columns are empty.

`1st row`  is a big header without any purpose for my code, I skip it in iteration.

`2nd row` headers of columns.

When I print values I skip header and start from 3rd row.

`for row_idx in range (3,rows)`

And I see only values from rows `3:201`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why I don't see value in row 202, If I iterate from `3` to `max_row (202)`. it will be wrong to use `for row_idx in range (3,rows+1)`:

Comment: Don't use your own counters, just use `ws.iter_rows()`. openpyxl knows how big the worksheet is and uses a 1-based index.

Comment: Thank you. But it became inconveniently to use my old alghorytm to find `cell.row` and `cell.column` by value.

Comment: Without seeing your code I don't really understand the problem but `cell.row` and `cell.column` are already available? In any case what openpyxl reports is correct: the max row in the worksheet is 202 as in `A202`

Comment: Works fine, I'm just not familiar with such syntax.